# Deploy Google App Engine Java Eclipse project with gcloud app deploy

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I usually use Eclipse and Google Cloud Tools plugin for Eclipse so I'm not really familiar with the command line tools. Now I have some deployment issues and I'd like to try to deploy using "gcloud app deploy".

I installed Google Cloud SDK and managed to run this:

```
cd D:\path-to-eclipse-workspace\my-project
C:\path-to-google-cloud\gcloud app deploy src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\appengine-web.xml -v v1
```

The deployment seems to work, but when I check on appspot.com my servlets are not there - I get: **Error: Not Found. The requested URL /hello was not found on this server.**

Thanks!

**Update:**

It looks like Eclipse is not putting **.class** files in **WEB-INF/classes** folder, but it creates a **build/classes** folder in the root of the project.

So, should I just copy the **classes** folder to **WEB-INF** before deployment or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Please show us your appengine-web.xml file and the Java class where you defined the servlet for the /hello endpoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up doing this:

1. Configure Eclipse to put **.class** files in **WEB_INF/classes** folder:

Project Properties -> Java Build Path -> Source -> configure **Default output folder** to be **WEB_INF/classes**

2. Deploy to App Engine:

`cd D:\path-to-eclipse-workspace\my-project
gcloud app deploy src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\appengine-web.xml -v v1`